# mysql id = snakeflakeId return not match rows

Tags: mysql

My project use snakeFlake to generate id, and my id columns type is bigint(10).

There is a table named ex has two rows:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1768475217040121858 | Name1 |
| 1768475217040121859 | Name2 |

```sql
// sql1
SELECT * FROM ex WHERE id = 1768475217040121858;
```

Sql above get all two rows.

```sql
// sql2
SELECT * FROM ex WHERE id = '1768475217040121858';
```

Sql above only return row 1.

My question is why sql1 return both rows, even row 2's id actually didn't match.

I've search mysql id = snakeFlakeId return didn't match rows in bing and google, but nothing got.

Change key words seems hepless.

**Finally, I found someone else change my id type to varchar(32).After change id type to bigint(20), sql1 successfully return row 1.But why in sql1 id type varchar(32) with value '1768475217040121859' can match value 1768475217040121858?**

Comment: How can `1768475217040121858` fit into a `BIGINT(10)` ?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen bigint range for -9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775807, so it can store 1768475217040121858.